# change the style with 'selectAll' and 'select' problems

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to change the style of some svg element.
when I do this:

```
var circleSelected = d3.select("#circleid_2");
        circleSelected.style("fill", "purple");
        circleSelected.style("stroke-width", 5);
        circleSelected.style("stroke", "red");
```

the circle is changing its style.

BUT, when i do this:

```
 var allCircles = d3.selectAll(".circle");
        allCircles.forEach(function (circle) {
            circle.style("fill", "green"); //function(d) { return getNodeColor(d); }
        });
```

it does not work with the error: Object [object SVGCircleElement] has no method 'style'

and here is my 'circle' declaration (note: it has both class and id):

```
node.append("circle")
            .attr("id", function (d) { return "circleid_" + d.id; })
            .attr("class", "circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return 0; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return 0; })
            .attr("r", function (d) { return getNodeSize(d); })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return getNodeColor(d); })
            .style("stroke", function (d) { return getNodeStrokeColor(d); })
            .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return getNodeStrokeWidth(d); });
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: And if you want to iterate you should use each function. Check this: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#each

In my case, the callback wasn't receiving parameters, I had to use: d3.select(this)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
d3.selectAll("circle").style("fill", "green");
```

Or:

```
allCircles.style("fill", "PaleGoldenRod");
```

**Explanation**: `d3.selectAll` will return a selection, which can be acted upon using the functions described in this API: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#selections-d3-selection

However, as soon as you do `forEach`, the internal variable returned each time as `circle` will be an actual DOM element - no longer a selection, and therefore no `style` function attached.

Comment: interesting.. if forEach returns a DOM element, then I can style it using jQuery, correct?

Comment: Yes, mixing jquery and d3 is a very common practice.